# Running separate process from Java applet using internal class

Tags: java, process, applet, classpath

I need to run separate process from Java applet. I want to use class, which lie inside jar:

```
myApplet.jar
 - packagename.MainApplet.class
 - packagename.ProcToRun.class
```

File `MainApplet` has interface Applet implementation and from inside of this code I'd like to run `ProcToRun` class as separete process. ProcToRun **has** main method.

I've tried code like this:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", ".;./myApplet.jar", ProcToRun.class.getName()).start();
```

and similar (`Runtime.exec(command)`, different notation - \\, / or with full url), but I got:

> Error: Could not find or load main class packagename.ProcToRun

Java.exe is visible, applet is signed - have all permissions, using win 8.1, java 8 u 25. I think there is something wrong with classpath, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: You'll be very, very lucky if an `Applet` is allowed to execute a external process.  `ProcToRun` obviously doesn't have a `main` method...applets don't (have `main` methods)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know, that applet don't have main method, but external process needs it and class `ProcToRun` does have it. Running from command line exactly from applet's jar works well.

Comment: You've tried executing the `Process` from a web browser?  I'd be worried cause that means you applet permissions are WIDE open...and if that's the case, I know some really good web sites you need to visit ;)

Comment: My applet works in intranet infrastructure, and I know all risks and dangerous situations, which go with that. I really need it to run other process. I've not tested running from other jar file yet.

Comment: You either need to run the applet browser or launch the applet via a web browser/html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java command cannot use URLs for the Jar to run, so it would be necessary to download the Jar explicitly to the local file system before attempting to run it.

But on seeing a `Process`, two tips:

1. See [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.
2. But the applet should establish an `URLClassLoader` pointing to the Jar, then invoke the constructor or `main(String[])` of interest.  If necessary, wrap the call in a `SwingWorker`.

Comment: I was thinking about this and it seems to be a right solution.

Comment: *"..it seems to be a right solution."* With 'it' being option 1 or option 2?  I prefer option 2.

Comment: I mean downloading the jar file. Agree, second option is better.